# check overlapping ranges in javascript from-to variable for each range

Tags: javascript, typescript

While developing an angular app, I now need to do a simple task, but surprisingly complicated.
I have some solutions, but I feel that none of them are quite right...
The problem is I'm given a possible unlimited(limited) number of [start, end] values, that represent the start and end of a number range. lets say:

```
    const rangeArr =[[5,10], [15,20], [9,14]];
```

I now need a function that checks overlaping of any of these ranges over any of the other ranges.
meaning that in this example the last one **[9,14]** overlaps with the first one **[5,10]**

I'm doing this reduce like this to find an index of an overlapping array:

```
rangeArr.findIndex((range:[number,number], index: number, arr:[number,number][])=>{
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length-1;i++){
  if(index === i)continue;
  if(range[0]>=arr[index][0] && range[0]<=arr[index][1]){
    return true;
  }
  if(range[1]>=arr[index][0] && range[1]<=arr[index][1]){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
})
```

I went for a classic solution...
However I'm convinced there is a simpler, less code solution for this...

Comment: do you need to do this more than once? if yes we should sort for index and use binary search otherwise we can do linear search

Answer (score 0):

This is the linear method. please answer the question if you need something that runs more than once:

```
  function interaction(r1: [number, number], r2: [number, number]): boolean {
    if (r1[0] <= r2[0] && r1[1] >= r2[0]) return true
    if (r1[0] <= r2[1] && r1[1] >= r2[0]) return true
    if (r2[0] <= r1[0] && r2[1] >= r1[0]) return true
    if (r2[0] <= r1[1] && r2[0] >= r1[1]) return true

    return false
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < rangeArr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < rangeArr.length; j++) {
      if (interaction(rangeArr[i], rangeArr[j])) return true
    }
  }

  return false
```

Comment: note this code includes consistent range which means it doesn't care if r1 is completely inside r2 as long as it intersects it will be true

Comment: @TachibanaShin
the logic is that if the begining of the range or the end of the range is inside the other range than it over laps. if the whole range is lapping that the first condition will resolve. so yes... as long as it interacts is overlaping.

Comment: @jeremy-denis since forEach is never checked it's stupid to keep looking for an already defined result

Comment: @jeremy-denis this is code written for humans so if you want to read write like me optimization is a matter of minifier and interpreter